# Handle the same URL with Spring MVC RequestMappingHandlerMapping and Spring Websocket's ServletWebSocketHandlerRegistry

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

What do I want to have:

- Client sends `GET / HTTP/1.1`(without `Connection: upgrade`) - this request should be handled by `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`
- Client sends `Connection: upgrade` along with GET request - this request should be handled by `ServletWebSocketHandlerRegistry`

My Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebsocketConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport 
                                    implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    @Bean
    WebsocketComponent wsHandler() {
        return new WebsocketComponent();
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(wsHandler(), "/").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

My webmvc controller:

```
@Controller
public class Status {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String status() {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

The problem is - when MVC controller taking precedence, it always respond with HTTP 200, WebSocket handler never reached. When WebSocket handler have precedence - it works with WebSocket client, but when I try http client(browser) it responds with `Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket".`
Is it possible to replace somehow this error page with fallback to my MVC mapping? Any other configurations to make what I described first?

Comment: Are sure of the fact that Spring MVC's request mappings take lower precedence over WebSocket mappings? For example, can you open a web socket connection on `ws://localhost:8080/status`?

Comment: @AliDehghani sure, websocket connection works, plain http connection didn't work with: 
00:30:20 ERROR Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null

Comment: Apparently, your `WebSocketHandlerMapping` has more precedence over your `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. It's usually the other way around, please post more about your configurations

Comment: @AliDehghani when `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` have precedence there are no place to fallback at all, see updated question

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you want both on the same url? Why not to give some different uri for websockets?

Comment: @AleksandrM 1) that is the way how my legacy application work, I want to use spring-websockets instead of handwritten websocket server and remain compatible with clients 2) it's better to have more descriptive message with instructions than cryptic `can upgrade only to websocket`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The problem is - when MVC controller taking precedence, it always
>   respond with HTTP 200, WebSocket handler never reached

When `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` takes precedence over `WebSocketHandlerMapping`, for a request to an endpoint that both of them can handle (If you just consider the URL), `DispatcherServlet` would dispatch the request to `@RequestMapping` methods, not the WebSocket handler. In order to solve this problem, restrict `@RequestMapping` method to just serve the request without `Connection:Upgrade` header:

```
@Controller
public class Status {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET, headers = "Connection!=Upgrade")
    public String status() {
        return "OK";
    }
}
```

This way, when `DispatcherServlet` searches for a handler for that common endpoint, it would consider the presence or absence of the `Connection:Upgrade` header to determine the right handler to fulfill the request.

Comment: Great explanation!
In my case I had to double the test: `headers = {"Connection!=upgrade", "Connection!=Upgrade" }`